# QWebChannel in Qt-Android app

Tags: javascript, html, qt

I am developing an app for Android/iOs/Windows using Qt with UI in html.
When I try to communicate from my html to JavaScript, it is fine, but when I try from JS to C++, it is not working.

Everywhere, I am getting examples using WebKit, but not with WebEngine. I also tried QWebChannel example for Qt, but that doesn't seem to help.

Can someone tell me how to use QWebChannel in my app in which I want to communicate from HTML/JS to C++ and vice-versa ?

Answer (score 1):

For Javascript -> C++ communication look at this API reference:
[Qt WebChannel JavaScript API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html)

For C++ -> Javascript communication look at the [Qt WebChannel Standalone Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-standalone-example.html)

If you are using QWebEngine you can use `qt.webChannelTransport` as your transport object when initializing the `QWebChannel` object after loading the `qwebchannel.js` script provided by Qt